# Changing global configuration in VMware Workstation 8

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I'd like to suppress the "accept license" dialog (et al.) that appears when a user first launches VMware Workstation 8.  I know that having a `C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini` containing:

```
pref.eula.0.appName = "VMware Workstation"
pref.eula.0.buildNumber = "123456"
msg.autoAnswer = "TRUE"
hints.hideAll = "TRUE"
```

Will accomplish this on a per-user basis, however I'd like for this to just be the default.  I tried adding these settings to `C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\config.ini` without success.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is an `All Users` profile that lets you store custom profile data for all users. The data is overlayed on top of all user profiles, even existing ones and new ones that are created later.

So you'd just put `C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini` into `C:\Users\All Users\AppData\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini` along with any other files that may be required to ensure a consistent vmware profile. Be warned, however, that I haven't tried this, and it's entirely possible that VMware may choose to write their software not to even look at All Users, or Default User, or anything but the actual current user's profile.

The other option is to enforce a logon script that manually copies the files to the user's own profile if they don't already exist. Try [these instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908.aspx). This is the more reliable method IMHO, because you're literally putting the file exactly where VMware would naturally expect it to be, and you don't have to worry about having two `preferences.ini` (one in All Users and one in the user's profile) and the possibility of conflicts, etc. You can just drop in a default copy of the preferences file, checking in your script whether or not it already exists before doing the copy.

Answer (score 0):

If a user would like those settings to be global, they can edit the `config.ini` in either of the following locations (I'm not sure how it inherits and which is the "master").

Windows Host: `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\VMware\VMware Workstation\config.ini`

Another copy located at `C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\config.ini`

Its possible the one you mentioned at `C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\config.ini` doesn't control the user specific settings, but only system specific settings.